# Mapping an input file to different RDDs

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a text file consisting of columns of integers. Assuming that I have N number of columns, I need to have N-1 number of PairRDDs. Each PairRDD has one of the 0 to N-2 columns of my file as Key and the last column as Value. Number of columns in my file varies each time I run the program so I don't know the number of RDDs before the run.

Code below gives `task not serializable` error.

```
val inputFile = sc.textFile(path).persist();
for (dim <- 0 to (numberOfColumns - 2)){            
  val temp = inputFile.map(line => {
    val lines = line.split(',')
    (lines(dim), lines(numberOfColumns - 1))
  })
}
```

I appreciate any help for solving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my code, I had references to the global fields of the class. So Spark had to send the whole class instance to the executors to access those fields and my class was not serializable.

I copied all the global fields as local variables in my method so just the local variables were sent to the executors and the problem got solved.

Answer (score 2):

Move the operation you are performing outside the calling class to a serialized class or to an object:

```
class RDDOperation extends Serializable {

  def perform(inputFile: RDD[String], numberOfColumns: Int) = {
    for (dim <- 0 to (numberOfColumns - 2)) yield {
      inputFile.map(line => {
        val lines = line.split(',')
        (lines(dim), lines(numberOfColumns - 1))
      })
    }
  }
}
```

The reason for the exception is that RDD's elements are partitioned across the nodes of the cluster. So when we use map/flatMap on an RDD all the operation happen on multiple nodes so the operation being performed inside map must be serialized. Hence moving it to a serialized class or an object will make it serialized.

And prefer returning values in scala functions hence I have used yield here which will return a collection of pairRDDs.

Also, you can refactor the perform method which doesn't depend on numberOfColumns like this:

```
def perform(inputFile: RDD[String]): RDD[(String, String)] = {
    inputFile.flatMap{ line =>
      val lines = line.split(',').toList

      lines.reverse match {
        case lastColumn :: _ => lines.flatMap{
          case column if column != lastColumn => Some((column, lastColumn))
          case _ => None
        }
        case _ => List.empty[(String, String)]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had references to the fields of my class inside my method. I copied all those global fields as local variables and ran the program again. Method was executed correctly without any serialization errors. However I am using Spark locally. Do you think if I run the program on the cluster I will have serialization issues?

Comment: If your program running without any serialization issue on local then there won't be any issues on cluster too. When running spark locally it takes the cores you have provided to it as separate nodes. So let's assume you have a machine with 4 cores and provided "local[*]" in the master configuration then spark will choose one driver node and other cores will become worker node. So it mimics the cluster in standalone mode.